# Behaviour of SELECT @Var and SET @Var in T-SQL when dealing with NULLs

Tags: sql, t-sql, select

Everyday I learn something new, it seems :) Can someone please explain to me the rationale behind the following code behavior:

```
DECLARE @A INT

SET @A = 15
SET @A = (SELECT ValueThatDoesntExist FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE MyColumn = 'notfound')

SELECT @A
-- Rsultset is NULL

SET @A = 15
SELECT @A = ValueThatDoesntExist FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE MyColumn = 'notfound'

SELECT @A
-- Resultset is 15
```

From what I see, SET changes the value of the variable if the resultset is NULL, while SELECT doesn't. Is this normal ANSI behavior or is it T-SQL specific?

Of, course, if I do `SELECT @A = NULL`, the assignment happens correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first version sets A to the result of a query:

```
SET @A = (SELECT ValueThatDoesntExist FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE MyColumn = 'notfound')
```

Basically the `select` in in scalar context, and if it doesn't find a row, it evaluates to `null`.

The second version sets A for **each row** in the result set:

```
SELECT @A = ValueThatDoesntExist FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE MyColumn = 'notfound'
```

Since there are no rows, A is never assigned to.  Another example:

```
declare @a int

select  @a = i
from    (
        select  1
        union all select 2
        union all select 3
        ) as SubQueryAlias(i)
order by
        i

select  @a
```

This will assign 3 values to `@a`.  The last one assigned is `3`, so that's what the query prints.

Comment: For your last example - I'm not sure that you're *guaranteed* that `@a` will be `3` afterwards, nor that 3 assignments will be performed.

Answer (score 2):

Well the select returns no rows. So practically there is not assignment.

While the set will have a null as a result.

Answer (score 2):

Variable assignment in a `SELECT` clause is rather unpredictable. When you have:

```
SELECT @A = ...
```

and *exactly* one row is in the result set, the value is well defined. If *multiple* rows are returned, the value *may* be computed once, for an arbitrary row, or it may be computed *multiple* times, up to the number of rows in the result set.

However, if the query produces *zero* rows, then the assignment is never performed.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @A = (SELECT ValueThatDoesntExist 
                       FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE MyColumn = 'notfound')
```

Here NULL is returned  as a result of executing the query

But when you do

```
SELECT @A = ValueThatDoesntExist FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE MyColumn = 'notfound'
```

there is nothing returned from the query